# Dog vs Cat: How is the data labelled?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a dog vs cat classifier but cannot figure out where the classification data exists. In the case of the titanic competition on kaggle the data existed in the Survived(0 or 1) column.

However, how does the CNN know which is being classified as dog or cat? I have posted my code below.

```
from keras import layers 
from keras import models 

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
metrics=['acc'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
target_size=(150,150),
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_dir,
target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_dir,
target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')



history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=30,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=50)






train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
```

I understand that this directory is being created and all the training files are loaded into this (theres is a seperate code for it). Additionally, in that process it seperates the images into cat folder and dog folder. Is this analogous to the titanic Survived column?

Answer (score 3):

The `ImageDataGenerator` class has two methods `flow()` and `flow_from_directory()` to read the images from a big `numpy` array and **folders containing images**.

So in case of using `flow_from_directory()` function, You won't have to specify the label and the keras itself does everything.
You just have to put your train and validation images in folders and sub folders like this:

```
/train
      |
      /cat
         /cat1.jpg
         /cat2.jpg
      /dog
         /dog1.jpg
         /dog2.jpg
```

So by this arrangement of folders, `flow_from_directory()` function will do the labeling itself.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

So in the case of ship detection challenge (https://www.kaggle.com/c/airbus-ship-detection) can I simply put the image files into Has_ship and no_has_ship ? Also when giving the output does keras output as 0 and 1 in case of binary classification?

Comment: In case of binary classification, Yes. Your foldering will be correct